Null values in diff bucket iceberg
let say I have col A,B,C,D,E in a iceberg table and my partition spec looks like:-
PartitionSpec.builderFor(getSchema())
                .month(A).identity(B)
                .bucket(C, 1)
                .build();

Now I want that all the values where C is null go to one bucket and all not nulls to another bucket, how to achieve that using iceberg without adding any new column.
